# Dealing with unindentified characters in data mining in R

Tags: r, pdf, encoding, data-mining

I am trying to extract data from a pdf file in R by using mainly the `pdftools` package. I have some tables in pdf format, and I want to make it a beautiful datatable. So I am doing various things to tidy the results, including a list of charaters to remove :

```
CaracteresASupprimer <- c("\r", "\001", "\002")

CF_synthese_4 <- gsub(paste(CaracteresASupprimer, collapse = '|'), "", CF_synthese_3) # On supprime des caracteres speciaux lies par exemple Ã  la hausse ou la baisse
```

It seems one of the pdf file I regularly use has changed something, but I now get characters that do not seems to be recognized, marked as squares (`"", ""`). They correspond to special characters in the pdf file, but used to be coded in a way that coule be anticipated (`\001`, etc.). They can be seen in the screenshot : [image].

I can copy paste these squares as characters to remove, with something like `CaracteresASupprimer <- c("\r", "\001", "\002, "", "")` but :

- There are different kind of squares (3 actually)
- They cannot be saved in standard encoding (ISO-8859-1), and even if saving in UTF-8 it does not seem to work each time (sometimes they are transformed as things like `"ïƒ¢", "ïƒ¢", "ïƒ¢", "ïƒ¡"`
- It is not really comfortable in terms of reproductibility/understanding

When I try to `dput` the data to have a MWE, these characters become `<U+F0E2>` and `<U+F0E2>`, but here it is :

```
list("   Belgium                        1.4       -6.3 <U+F0E2>      5.0 <U+F0E1>     1.4        0.5       1.1  <U+F0E1>        -6.5        -7.0        -6.1\r", 
    "   Canada                         1.6       -6.8 <U+F0E2>      5.3 <U+F0E1>     1.9        0.6 <U+F0E2>     1.8  <U+F0E2>      -34.2        -53.7       -48.0\r", 
    "   France                         1.3       -8.2 <U+F0E2>      6.7 <U+F0E1>     1.1        0.3 <U+F0E2>     1.2  <U+F0E2>      -18.7        -15.5       -18.4\r", 
    "   Germany                        0.6       -6.3 <U+F0E2>      5.2 <U+F0E1>     1.4        0.6 <U+F0E2>     1.4         274.8       219.0       236.0\r", 
    "   Italy                          0.3       -9.9 <U+F0E2>      6.3 <U+F0E1>     0.6       -0.2       0.6          59.8         50.1        50.6\r", 
    "   Japan                          0.7       -5.5 <U+F0E2>      2.4 <U+F0E1>     0.5       -0.4 <U+F0E2>     0.1  <U+F0E2>      181.9       174.8       185.8\r", 
    "   Netherlands                    1.8       -6.2 <U+F0E2>      4.7 <U+F0E2>     2.6        0.6 <U+F0E2>     1.2  <U+F0E2>       92.9         75.4        84.5\r", 
    "   Norway                         2.3       -6.3 <U+F0E1>      5.9 <U+F0E2>     2.2        0.9 <U+F0E2>     2.1  <U+F0E1>       15.9          7.6        13.1\r", 
    "   Spain                          2.0       -9.1 <U+F0E2>      6.7 <U+F0E1>     0.7       -0.4       1.0  <U+F0E2>       26.8         17.3        16.4\r", 
    "   Sweden                         1.2       -5.7 <U+F0E2>      4.5 <U+F0E2>     1.8        0.4 <U+F0E2>     1.3  <U+F0E2>       20.8         16.0        19.5\r", 
    "   Switzerland                    0.9       -5.5 <U+F0E2>      4.3 <U+F0E1>     0.4       -0.7 <U+F0E2>     0.3  <U+F0E2>       86.1         57.2        62.9\r", 
    "   United Kingdom                 1.4       -7.9 <U+F0E2>      6.1 <U+F0E1>     1.8        1.0       1.4  <U+F0E2>     -107.0        -89.2       -97.1\r", 
    "   United States                  2.3       -5.4 <U+F0E2>      4.3 <U+F0E1>     1.8        0.7 <U+F0E2>     1.8        -498.4      -416.4      -489.1\r", 
    "   North America1                 2.2       -5.5        4.3       1.8        0.7       1.8        -532.6      -470.1      -537.1\r", 
    "   Western Europe2                1.3       -7.4        5.7       1.3        0.4       1.1         444.1       369.8       402.9\r", 
    "   European Union2                1.4       -7.2        5.6       1.3        0.5       1.2         447.5       385.0       418.8\r", 
    "   Euro zone2                     1.2       -7.9 <U+F0E2>      6.2 <U+F0E1>     1.2        0.3 <U+F0E2>     1.1 <U+F0E2>       358.2       294.0       330.6\r", 
    "   Asia Pacific3                  4.1       -1.0        6.0       2.2        2.0       1.7         486.3       467.8       507.2\r", 
    "   Eastern Europe4,7              2.4       -3.4        3.9       5.5        5.4       4.7          53.3        -35.4       -10.8\r", 
    "   LatAm ex Venezuela5 ,7         0.6       -4.0        3.0      10.1        8.2       7.8         -90.5        -84.7       -94.8\r", 
    "   Other Countries6               2.0       -3.2        3.1       4.5        5.1       5.7          26.5        -50.1       -38.6\r", 
    "  Total7                              2.5       -4.1        5.1       2.7        2.0       2.3\r")
```

So my question is two-folds:

- Why is this happening ? How come these signs (arrows in the pdf text) end up like this ?
- Is there a generic command to remove all unindentified characters, that would be more robust than using these pasted squares and enable not to change standard enconding ?

If there are any recommendation to do this in a better way I am of course willing to take them !

Comment: Have you tried to use `gsub([^[:alnum:]],"", CF_synthese_3)`. `[[:alnum:]]` Removes everything except alpha numeric characters. Use `?regex` in your command line in `R` for more details.

Comment: It also removes spacing, that enables me to split the rows subsequently, and the points between my figures, which is a problem too.

Comment: In that case: `trimws(gsub("\\s+"," ", gsub("[^[:alnum:]]"," ", CF_synthese_3)))`. Not the best solution at all, but makes the work done.

Comment: _I can copy paste these squares as characters…_. Please [edit] the question and paste them _here_. Please paste here each different kind of squares along with some context (a few neighbour chars). Consider applying something like a [rawConversion](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.0.3/topics/rawConversion) to get Unicode codepoints, see `rawToChar(y)` in the example there.

Comment: @JosefZ I have edited my question, and will look at the path you suggested

Comment: Characters in Unicode range `U+E000`..`U+F8FF` are _Private Use_. Hence, I don't comprehend where they come from. The only thing I can tell is their UTF-8 representation (byte sequences): `U+F0E1` => `0xEF`,`0x83`,`0xA1` (`ï�¡`)  and `U+F0E2` => `0xEF`,`0x83`,`0xA2` (`ï�¢`).